# detect when uploadValues is completed?

Tags: c#, php

I want to display a message box after posting data to a remote php file..

**PS: The php file return the string "END" when the data is completely processed**

```
if (1 == outputToGui)
{
    CompressFile("allFilesList.txt");

    byte[] allFilesList = File.ReadAllBytes("allFilesList.txt.gz");
    string URIx = "http://example.com/post.php";
    System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
    data.Add("serial", serial);
    data.Add("data", Convert.ToBase64String(allFilesList));
    using (WebClient tayba = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            tayba.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            tayba.Proxy = null;
            tayba.UploadValues(URIx, "POST", data);
        }
        catch (Exception E) { }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("upload completed"); // this message show up before the php file process the posted data sometimes.. ?!!!!
```

The problem is that the message box show up before the php file process the posted data sometimes.. ?!!!!

Comment: can you not implement this using `async Task ` or something similar

Comment: Are you sure the code is executing correctly? If `outputToGui` isn't 1 or an exception is thrown, you'll see the MessageBox quickly. It could seem that it's firing before you receive a response even though you aren't actually receiving a response. Move `MessageBox.Show` into the `if` and don't catch `Exception`. This way you'll know if the issue is `outputToGui` or an exception being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because operation is asynchronous. Upload might still be in progress when messagebox is called.

Search webclient for correct completion event and add your message there. META: _webClient.eventName += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show("Ta-dah!");

Assign event listener before you start the upload.

Comment: Isn't `UploadValuesAsync` the asynchronous version? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900ted1f(v=vs.110).aspx) says `UploadValues` will block during execution? Am I missing something here?

Comment: With information given, can't see any other possibility than `outputToGui != 1` or `Exception` is thrown.

Comment: I'm thinking the same thing.